# How much free space does my device need to cache template using DocuSign SDK on Android?

Tags: android, docusignapi

How much free space does my device need to cache a template using DocuSign SDK on Android?
when I use the cacheTemplate function I'm getting "Insufficient disk space." message error, even if I have 1.6 GB free on my Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minimum disk space should be 4GB to cache a template using DocuSign Android SDK.